# Where to put the parentheses in the sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, parentheses

I want to add extra information in my sentence for the sake of clarity by using parentheses. Should I put them at the end or right after the word(s) they are related to?

For example, which of the followings is best?

a) They differ in their first layer of the network by replacing X with Y (after the input layer).

b) They differ in their first layer (after the input layer) of the network by replacing X with Y.

c) They differ in their first layer of the network (after the input layer) by replacing X with Y.

Comment: If this is a neural network then you could skip the parenthetical and just use "first hidden layer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babak. (c) is definitely the construction you want. (a)'s setup may not actually produce ambiguity, but it could, and it's awkward. (b) is über-awkward, with "of the network" hanging out there, lonely. --James